# Access Buffer - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, buffer

I have this very simple code written in javascript.

```
 let str = "Hello World";
console.log(Buffer.from(str,"utf-8"));
```

result: `<Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64>`

How can i get the bytes from the Buffer? So result will look like this

expected result `48656c6c6f20576f726c64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node's `Buffer` includes a [`toString`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buftostringencoding-start-end) method for this purpose. You can supply the desired *encoding* format as the first argument. In your case, you can use `"hex"` meaning *hexadecimal*:

```js
const str = 'Hello World';
const buf = Buffer.from(str, 'utf-8');
const hex = buf.toString('hex');
console.log(hex === '48656c6c6f20576f726c64'); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you iterate the values since `Buffer` has that method and more. It's quite array-like. Use `toString(16)` to convert to hex.

```js
let str = "Hello World";
var buf = Buffer.from(str, "utf-8");
var result = [];
buf.forEach(function(value) {
  result.push(value.toString(16))
})

console.log(result.join(""));
```